# Any downside to downgrading to 18" wheels on my 2021 Honda Accord Touring?

Tags: tires, wheels

My 2021 Honda Accord 2.0T Touring comes with stock 19" wheels. The tyre is low profile and my commute has a ton of pot holes. Its my understanding that I can just replace this with 18" wheels as long as I get the correct tyre size.

Is there any safety issue to making this change?

Comment: If you're worried about your low profile and potholes, why would you want a smaller wheel?

Comment: @barbecue - Smaller wheel with same diameter (overall) tire gives you larger sidewall with more flex and better ride quality over rough terrain (like potholes).

Comment: Ah, I missed that the OP was changing tire size.

Comment: Tire aspect ratio, the sidewall distance between rim and tread to rim width, results in low, medium and regular side profiles. Years ago, someone I knew bought a VW Corrado with low aspect ratio tires, 40 or 45 series. In NYC, he broke all his rims from potholes, costing $1600. Expensive learning lesson not to buy low profile tires if driving on known terrible streets and roads. 55 series might be moderate with 70 series as regular tires.  I have 55 series tires on my 4 dr sedan and haven't blown out a tire in NYC driving yet (16 yrs).